# VLC: Restart need after changing settings

Tags: vlc-media-player

I'm trying to use VLC to take a number of screenshots from a number of videos... The location for the resulting screenshots varies slightly for each video, as does the naming convention. Both of these settings are configured in `Tools > Peferences > Video > Video Snapshots`.

However, I've found that after making changes to these settings they are not being recognised....until VLC is restarted.

I assume that this is a 'feature' common to everyone, and not just a bug with my version.

It's not the end of the world, but it's very annoying to have to restart the app after each change. And there doesn't seem to be any good justification for it - I can't see why it would be required; I assume it is just an oversight.

Is this a common experience? Is there any way around it... any way to coax the app into accepting modified settings without a restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a common experience. I have had the same behaviour with all versions of vlc I have used (that's a *lot*, I have been using vlc for many years) on both linux and windows operating systems.

Feature? Bug? Dunno.

Comment: Yup; sadly it’s just a shortcoming that has *yet* to be addressed.